# How do I create this Transparent Dialog/Canvas for Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner Android developer and I'm making my first app. I'd like to make a simple view that is overlayed on the map with a semi-transparent background. This is what it would hopefully look like:

[image]

As you can see, one of these dialogs/windows has a simple integer displayed and the other will have a rendered graph/chart.

What would be the best way to go about making this? A dialog? The problem with that might be that I would for the user to be able to work with the mapview below while this is displayed. And I'm not sure if a simple transparent rectangular canvas is the right way to get this done.

Any suggestions/ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways to go

-Make it a `FrameLayout` so add MapFragment first then add a `Linearlayout` with `orientation horizontal` and make `gravity top` and `translucent background`,so it will be displayed on top of map, and it will also involve the elements inside,

-Instead of `FrameLayout` make it a `RelativeLayout` and the same process as above.

-Make the overlay as seperate `Activity`(which is the worst case scenario)
Sample code for overlay can be like this

```
<LinearLayout
       ....
 android:divider=".." // some drawable or color whatever you want
 android:showDividers="middle"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="a000">
    <TextView
     ....
     android:value="58"/>
    <com.example.custom.view
     ..../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `RelativeLayout` on the top of the MapFragment, with a black background and some opacity (for that you can use a drawable).

Then, on the `RelativeLayout` you can add other controls like `TextView` and `ImageView`

I don't recommand you to use a Dialog, since it sounds like it's not corresponding to your needs.

Comment: Hmm ok. This sounds like something I could definitely do. If I wanted to add a number of features to this though, would it get overly complicated to organize it?

Comment: I don't think so, since you can add any kind of layout inside your RelativeLayout, so it should be very simple.